# Animate background on listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-cursoradapter, android-drawable

I have a ListView that have in each row 2 TextView and a CheckBox.

I have a drawable (a line), that I want once the user check the CheckBox that the drawable will be scale as an animation at the background of the checked CheckBox row, I was able in my **getView()** method on my Custom Adapter, to animate the drawable as a background but it also scale the 2 TextView and the CheckBox, and I want that only the drawable background will be scale as an animation, how do i do that?

here is my **getView()** method on the custom adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, parent, false);
    // cache view fields into the holder
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
    holder.itemQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemQuantity);
    holder.itemCheck = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheck);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    final Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    final View rowView = convertView;
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    holder.itemTitle.setText(cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME))));
    holder.itemQuantity.setText(cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_QUANTITY))));
    holder.itemCheck.setChecked(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_CHECKED)) == 1);

    holder.itemCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    itemsDataSource.updateItemCheckBox(1, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID)));
                    itemsDataSource.updateRoute(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME)), true);
                    Animation drawLine = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.item_done);
                    rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.line);
                    rowView.startAnimation(drawLine);
                    ShowListActivity.PRIORITY++;
                }
                else {
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    itemsDataSource.updateItemCheckBox(0, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID)));
                    itemsDataSource.updateRoute(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME)), false);
                    rowView.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    ShowListActivity.PRIORITY--;
                }

            }
        });
    if (holder.itemCheck.isChecked()) rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.line);
    else rowView.setBackgroundResource(0);
    return rowView;
}
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;
    TextView itemQuantity;
    CheckBox itemCheck;     
}
```

Comment: code can give better idea.

Comment: please share your code instead just a theory

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1515 read this tutorial with scale animation in Listview may be its helpful to you

Comment: *how do i do that?* - Don't set the drawable as the background of the entire row view, instead, use it as the background of an empty view and scale that view only.

Comment: I understand what you saying Luksprog, but how I'm adding the empty view to the row on the listview?

Comment: That really depends on how your row view looks like, where is the `CheckBox` placed etc.

Comment: can u give me an exaple or reffer me to one, that I can understand how to do that in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

I managed to solve the problem:

first I changed the custom row layout file like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frameRowLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:weightSum="10">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rowLayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/itemCheck" 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
            android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center" 
            android:focusable="false" 
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
            android:singleLine="false" />

       <TextView android:id="@+id/itemTitle" 
           android:layout_width="0dp" 
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
           android:layout_weight="6" 
           android:gravity="center" 
           android:text="some text1" 
           android:textColor="#2B89A8" 
           android:textSize="22dp" 
           android:textStyle="bold" />

       <TextView android:id="@+id/itemQuantity" 
           android:layout_width="0dp" 
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
           android:layout_weight="2" 
           android:gravity="center" 
           android:text="some text2" 
           android:textColor="#2B89A8" 
           android:textSize="22dp" 
           android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/backgroundView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

the whole idea of Framelayout is that views can overlap each other, there for the View after the LinearLayout is overlapping the LinearLayout.

then I changed my **getView()** method in my custom adapter as Following:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, parent, false);
    // cache view fields into the holder
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
    holder.itemQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemQuantity);
    holder.itemCheck = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheck);
    holder.rowView = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundView);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    final Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    holder.itemTitle.setText(cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME))));
    holder.itemQuantity.setText(cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_QUANTITY))));
    holder.itemCheck.setChecked(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_CHECKED)) == 1);

    holder.itemCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    itemsDataSource.updateItemCheckBox(1, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID)));
                    itemsDataSource.updateRoute(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME)), true);
                    Animation drawLine = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.item_done);
                    holder.rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.line);
                    holder.rowView.startAnimation(drawLine);
                    ShowListActivity.PRIORITY++;
                }
                else {
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    itemsDataSource.updateItemCheckBox(0, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID)));
                    itemsDataSource.updateRoute(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME)), false);
                    holder.rowView.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    ShowListActivity.PRIORITY--;
                }

            }
        });
    if (holder.itemCheck.isChecked()) holder.rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.line);
    else holder.rowView.setBackgroundResource(0);
    return convertView;
}
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;
    TextView itemQuantity;
    CheckBox itemCheck; 
    View rowView;
}
```

hope you can understand what I did.